# How to toggle full screen mode in GTK+/GTK#

Tags: mono, gtk, gtk#, gtk3

I am building my first GTK application.  I am writing my app in Mono C# using the GTK# bindings.  However, I will be happy to receive the GTK+ explanation and figure out the GTK# implementation.
The application consists of a single top level window that I wish to toggle fullscreen mode on and off in the same way that Chrome does with the F11 key.  I can go to full screen mode easily by executing the **GdkWindow.Fullscreen ()** method on the window object.  But, I cannot figure out how to toggle back  to 'Normal' mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, try calling [`Unfullscreen`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=M%3aGtk.Window.Unfullscreen) method (the effect is WM dependent, though).

Note, that fullscreen state may be tracked via [`Widget.WindowStateEvent`](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=E%3aGtk.Widget.WindowStateEvent) event.

Comment: Thank you, it was right in front of my nose.  Learning a new API can be a big task.  I was aware of that Widget.WindowStateEvent, also I found that I could check the GdkWindow.State value for the current state of the window as well.  Your answer was directly on point.